# Spring + Hibernate with Hazelcast as 2nd level cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, hazelcast

I have a spring project (spring core 3.1.2) configured with Hibernate (hibernate core 4.2.8) and i want to set up Hazelcast as a 2nd level cache. I want to have the cache distributed in P2P, embedded cluster mode (each application instance runs a hazelcast instance on the same machine).

This is my current sessionFactory configuration.

```
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myProject.beans" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.database">ORACLE</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <!--enable batch operations-->
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
                <!-- 2nd level cache configuration-->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This configuration seems to work on my local machine as i ran a small test that checks for a 2nd level cache hit.

The question is:
What other configurations must I make in order to have the cache distributed among the instances. How are the different machines going to "know about each other"?
Also, is there a way to create a test scenario that checks that the cache is indeed distributed among a couple of machines?(ex: launch 2 jvms) An example would be greatly appreciated.

Any other tips or warnings about this configuration are welcome.

Disclaimer: Its the first time I use Hazelcast.

My Hazelcast version is 3.5.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anymore config to form a cluster. 
Just start another instance of your app and two hazelcast instances should see each other and form a cluster.
By default hazelcast members uses multicast to find each other, of course you can change this behaviour by adding a custom `hazelcast.xml` to your project.

Here is a detailed example of Spring-Hibernate-Hazelcast integration.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-hibernate-2ndlevel-cache

`applicationContext-hazelcast.xml` is the file to modify if you want to play with Hazelcast config.
For example, in this sample project `port-auto-increment` is set to `false`
that means Hazelcast won't start if the specified port is already occupied. (5701 by default)

Just set this property to `true` and start another `Application` instance, you should see that the cache is distributed.

Please don't forget to comment out last line of `Application` class before starting first instance to keep processes alive

Start first instance like below;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InitializeDB.start();

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    DistributedMapDemonstrator distributedMapDemonstrator = context.getBean(DistributedMapDemonstrator.class);
    distributedMapDemonstrator.demonstrate();

    //Hazelcast.shutdownAll(); Keep instances alive to see form a cluster
}
```

And second one like below;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //InitializeDB.start(); DB will be initialized already by the first instance

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    DistributedMapDemonstrator distributedMapDemonstrator = context.getBean(DistributedMapDemonstrator.class);
    distributedMapDemonstrator.demonstrate();

    //Hazelcast.shutdownAll(); Keep instances alive to see form a cluster

}
```